# Encrypted (LUKS) Hard Drive Rejects Key File?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, encryption, 19.10

I have an internal hard drive encrypted using LUKS from the GNOME-Disks utility.

I usually unlock it from GNOME disks, but I'm trying to automate as much as I can, so I'm trying to do it from the command line.

The unlock from GNOME Disks works just fine, but I made a key file using vim that looks like this (Just containing the password and nothing else):

`PASSWORD_HERE`

However, unmounting from disks and then trying this command: `sudo udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sda1 --key-file="/home/sarah/Custom Programs/Configuration/ConvergentRefugeKey"` does not work and gives this error:

`Error unlocking /dev/sda1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.Failed: Error unlocking /dev/sda1: Failed to activate device: Incorrect passphrase.`

This is strange since I made *absolutely* certain that the only text in the key file was the decryption key that works from the disks utility.

Do I have the wrong format for the key file?

[image: Disks]

Comment: Have you added a newline at the end of your keyfile? In that case LUKS may include that in the passphrase it reads from the file. Try removing it or add the --keyfile-size parameter to specify the length of the passphrase to read.